# Run Java script on a web page owned by some third party web application

Tags: javascript, autofill, cross-site

I found one post with title as "Issue with Form Auto-Submit with JS code written in browser's address bar" and the solution provided worked for me.

Now my requirement is, I want to run my following javascript commands once the third party web application's login page has been loaded.

```
javascript:document.getElementById('Username').value='xyz';document.getElementById('Password').value='xyz_123';document.getElementById('Destination').value='TestDB';document.getElementById('cmdLogin1').click();
```

Please note that the application I am trying to login to is a third party application and I DO NOT HAVE ACCESS TO THE SOURCE CODE.

Currently what I am doing is, I have created a bookmark with URL as above mentioned code, when the login page is loaded, I am clicking on the bookmark and thus the login fields gets filled and page gets submitted automatically.

I just want to bypass this manual intervention and want some way to automatically run the above JS commands as soon as the login page loading is completed.

Please help.

Thanks
Shridhar

Comment: So, do you want to auto-fill a form or do you want to run your own JS on a website that isn't yours?

Comment: A browser with a proper password manager should be able to achieve that without any need for custom JS …

Comment: @CBroe I think the click will be hard

Comment: @Michael: Well the bookmarklet will likely not become active on its own, but will require a click either, I suppose …

Answer (score 3):

You can use a userscript for this, e.g.:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://<websiteUrlHere>
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

document.getElementById('Username').value='xyz';
document.getElementById('Password').value='xyz_123';
document.getElementById('Destination').value='TestDB';
document.getElementById('cmdLogin1').click();
```

Just replace the `@match` with the url you need this to run on, and load the userscript via [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=de) or [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), depending on the browser you are using - tampermonkey for chrome or greasemonkey for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

**Or** you can create a very **simple extension**:

You will need two files:

```js
yourCode.js // Here goes your code
manifest.json // Here you target the page
```

Here is what you should put in `manifest.json`:

```json
{

  "manifest_version": 2,         // Mandatory
  "name": "Auto-submit form",    // Mandatory
  "version": "1.0",              // Mandatory



  "content_scripts": [      // This key injects your js file into any target website.
    {
      "matches": ["your target url"], // Pattern: "*://*/*"
      "js": ["yourCode.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

And your code resides in `yourCode.js`:

```js
document.getElementById('Username').value='xyz';
document.getElementById('Password').value='xyz_123';
document.getElementById('Destination').value='TestDB';
document.getElementById('cmdLogin1').click();
```

Now you have your extension and can install it on your desired browser.

In Firefox go to about:debugging > This Firefox > Load Temporary Add-on

In Chrome go to chrome://extensions > Developer Mode > Load unpacked extension.